# How do I read in lines from a text file in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

This is what I have so far. Isn't this all that you need? I keep getting the error "Error: Unbound module Std"

```
let r file =
    let chan = open_in file in
    Std.input_list (chan)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

An imperative solution using just the standard library:

```
let read_file filename = 
let lines = ref [] in
let chan = open_in filename in
try
  while true; do
    lines := input_line chan :: !lines
  done; !lines
with End_of_file ->
  close_in chan;
  List.rev !lines ;;
```

If you have the [Batteries-included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/) library you could read a file into an Enum.t and iterate over it as follows:

```
let filelines = File.lines_of filename in
Enum.iter ( fun line -> (*Do something with line here*) ) filelines
```

Comment: fd leak detected in the extlib variant : input channel is not closed

Comment: Can you explain why are you chaining the while loop with an empty list? I think it never gets reached.

Comment: @Rizo It's to make the type system happy. Try entering that code in the REPL leaving out the [] (after the done;) you'll get: Error: This expression has type bytes list but an expression was expected of type unit. With the [] both the 'try' block and 'with' block both return a list.

Comment: @Rizo: probably it would be better to put !lines after the done; , but as you note it doesn't really matter since that code never gets reached.  I'll edit the answer above, though, to do this as it does kind of make more sense.

Answer (score 20):

If you have the OCaml Core library installed, then it is as simple as:

```
open Core.Std
let r file = In_channel.read_lines file
```

If you have `corebuild` installed, then you can just compile your code with it:

```
corebuild filename.byte
```

if your code resides in a file named `filename.ml`.

If you don't have the OCaml Core, or do not want to install it, or some other standard library implementation, then, of course, you can implement it using a vanilla OCaml's standard library. There is a function `input_line`, defined in the `Pervasives` module, that is automatically opened in all OCaml programs (i.e. all its definitions are accessible without further clarification with a module name). This function accepts a value of type `in_channel` and returns a line, that was read from the channel. Using this function you can implement the required function:

```
let read_lines name : string list =
  let ic = open_in name in
  let try_read () =
    try Some (input_line ic) with End_of_file -> None in
  let rec loop acc = match try_read () with
    | Some s -> loop (s :: acc)
    | None -> close_in ic; List.rev acc in
  loop []
```

This implementation uses recursion, and is much more natural to OCaml programming.

Comment: Thanks for the recursive implementation! I seem to understand most of your code except the 'List.rev acc in loop[]'. Could you please explain exactly what's going on?

Comment: data to list are prepended, so actually we can think of `acc` as a stack. When we finish loop (i.e., hit the stop condition) we reverse our stack, so that our function returns data in a normal order

Comment: That solution using Options and Recursion should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple recursive solution that does not accumulate the lines or use external libraries, but lets you read a line, process it using a function, read the next recursively until done, then exit cleanly.  The exit function closes the open filehandle and signals success to the calling program.

```
let read_lines file process =
  let in_ch = open_in file in
  let rec read_line () =
    let line = try input_line in_ch with End_of_file -> exit 0
    in (* process line in this block, then read the next line *)
       process line;
       read_line ();
in read_line ();;

read_lines some_file print_endline;;
```

Answer (score 3):

This reads the file's lines and prints each of them:

```
open Core.Std

let handle_line line =
  printf "Your line: %s \n" line

let () =
  let file_to_read = "./file_to_read.txt" in
  let lines = In_channel.read_lines file_to_read in
  List.iter ~f: handle_line lines
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive solution using Scanf:

```
let read_all_lines file_name =
  let in_channel = open_in file_name in
  let rec read_recursive lines =
    try
      Scanf.fscanf in_channel "%[^\r\n]\n" (fun x -> read_recursive (x :: lines))
    with
      End_of_file ->
        lines in
  let lines = read_recursive [] in
  let _ = close_in_noerr in_channel in
  List.rev (lines);;
```

**Usage:**

```
let all_lines = read_all_lines "input.txt";;
```

However, I'd prefer to stream line-by-line:

```
let make_reader file_name =
  let in_channel = open_in file_name in
  let closed = ref false in
  let read_next_line = fun () ->
    if !closed then
      None
    else
      try
        Some (Scanf.fscanf in_channel "%[^\r\n]\n" (fun x -> x))
      with
        End_of_file ->
          let _ = close_in_noerr in_channel in
          let _ = closed := true in
          None in
  read_next_line;;
```

**Usage:**

```
let read_next = make_reader "input.txt";;
let next_line = read_next ();;
```

And may be a bit of icing:

```
type reader = {read_next : unit -> string option};;

let make_reader file_name =
  let in_channel = open_in file_name in
  let closed = ref false in
  let read_next_line = fun () ->
    if !closed then
      None
    else
      try
        Some (Scanf.fscanf in_channel "%[^\r\n]\n" (fun x -> x))
      with
        End_of_file ->
          let _ = close_in_noerr in_channel in
          let _ = closed := true in
          None in
  {read_next = read_next_line};;
```

**Usage:**

```
let r = make_reader "input.txt";;
let next_line = r.read_next ();;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: [http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html#space](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html#space)

_**...Similarly, a line feed character in the format string matches either a single line feed or a carriage return followed by a line feed**_

So, this solution "should" work for both "\r\n" and "\n" style line endings (only tested on a Linux system).

Comment: all code snippets do not close input channels, hence leak file descriptors

Comment: @ygrek: Thanks! Fixed. May be it's better to let the calling party do the opening / closing business and have these functions take input channels instead.

Answer (score 2):

Another style to read lines from a file using Scanf "string indiciation" and zero-width character. It is like traditional imperative style.

```
open Scanf 
open Printf

(* little helper functions *)
let id x = x 
let const x = fun _ -> x
let read_line file = fscanf file "%s@\n" id 
let is_eof file = try fscanf file "%0c" (const false) with End_of_file -> true

let _ = 
  let file = open_in "/path/to/file" in 

  while not (is_eof file) do 
    let s = read_line file in
    (* do something with s *) 
    printf "%s\n" s 
  done;

  close_in file
```

NOTE:

1. read_line ignore one trailing \n, so if the last character of your file 
   is \n, it may seems like you have missed the last empty line.
2. when using of Scanf, due to bufferization, do not mix other low level reading on the same channel, otherwise it will result in strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This just loads the whole file into one big string, but you could always split it into a list later.

```ml
let read_file path =
  let channel = open_in path in
  let buffer = Buffer.create 1024 in
  let rec go () =
    try
      Buffer.add_channel buffer channel 1024; go ()
    with End_of_file ->
      Buffer.contents buffer in
  go ();;
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but there is another recursive variation that is interesting (at least in my opinion), without libraries or reversal:

```ml
let read_lines filename =
  let f = open_in filename in
  let rec loop () =
    try
      let next = input_line f in
      next :: loop ()
    with End_of_file ->
      close_in f;
      []
  in loop ()
```

Note that the `let next = ...` line is important, because it ensures that the next line is read *before* recursion.

Answer (score 2):

There are new modules `In_channel` and `Out_channel` in the standard library of OCaml version 4.14.0, which was released on 2022-03-28. [refer](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.14.0)

So now, we could easily read the content from a file as follows:

```ml
# let conx = In_channel.with_open_text "example.dat" In_channel.input_all;;
val conx : string = "hey!\nworld"
```

Say, the content of the `example.dat`:

```bash
hey!
world
```

Answer (score 1):

To build upon @alwaysday1's solution you can make a simple function that will read all of the lines of a file using `In_channel` from OCaml 4.14.0, and `Str` like so:

```ml
let read_lines file =
  In_channel.with_open_text file In_channel.input_all
  |> Str.(split (regexp "\n"))
```

This will produce a list of all lines in the file.

Comment: With just the standard library it would be `String.(split_on_char '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately the OCaml standard library is continuously improving. Since OCaml 5.1, one can do the following:

```
let read_lines (file_name : string) : string list =
  In_channel.with_open_text file_name In_channel.input_lines
```

The [`In_channel`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/In_channel.html) module contains several functions that are useful for file content reading.

Answer (score 1):

What happens with very large files? Maybe you don't want to read *all* lines, so why should you? A lazy list or sequence would be ideal. Fortunately as of OCaml 4.07 and later, we have the [`Seq`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) module which permits us to create a sequence of lines read from a file.

```
let rec read_lines_seq file () =
  match In_channel.input_line file with
  | None -> Seq.Nil
  | Some line -> Seq.Cons (line, read_lines_seq file)
```

Where we might get all of the lines from a file now with:

```
let read_lines file_name =
  In_channel.with_open_text 
    file_name 
    (fun file -> file |> read_lines_seq |> List.of_seq)
```

But we could use this just as easily to print all of the lines in a file without having to first generate a complete list and then iterate that.

OCaml 5.1 also introduces [`In_channel.fold_lines`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/In_channel.html#VALfold_lines) which could do much the same.

```
let read_lines file_name =
  In_channel.(
    with_open_text
      file_name
      (fun file -> file |> fold_lines (Fun.flip List.cons) [] 
                        |> List.rev)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

`Std.input_list` apparently requires [Extlib](http://code.google.com/p/ocaml-extlib/), which you should install on your system (`libextlib-ocaml` and `libextlib-ocaml-dev` on Debian systems).