# OCaml string length limitation when reading from stdin\file

Tags: ocaml, utop

As part of a Compiler Principles course I'm taking in my university, we're writing a compiler that's implemented in OCaml, which compiles Scheme code into CISC-like assembly (which is just C macros).
the basic operation of the compiler is such:

1. Read a `*.scm` file and convert it to an OCaml `string`.
2. Parse the string and perform various analyses.
3. Run a code generator on the AST output from the semantic analyzer, that outputs text into a `*.c` file.
4. Compile that file with GCC and run it in the terminal.

Well, all is good and well, except for this: I'm trying to read an input file, that's around 4000 lines long, and is basically one huge expressions that's a mix of Scheme `if` & `and`.
I'm executing the compiler via `utop`. When I try to read the input file, I immediately get a stack overflow error message. It is my initial guess that the file is just to large for OCaml to handle, but I wasn't able to find any documentation that would support this theory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you provide just the piece of code that reads the file ? did you try reducing your code to exhibit the issue ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774934/how-do-i-read-in-lines-from-a-text-file-in-ocaml ; I managed to read a 2MB file with 4000l in utop without any issue.

Comment: I'm guessing, but this has all the symptoms of using a non-tail-recursive function to read the file. Without the actual code, it's impossible to tell, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the limitation was the amount of maximum ram the OCaml is configured to use.

I ran the following command in the terminal in order to increase the quota:

`export OCAMLRUNPARAM="l=5555555555"`

This worked like a charm - I managed to read and compile the input file almost instantaneously.

For reference purposes, this is the code that reads the file:

```
let file_to_string input_file =
  let in_channel = open_in input_file in
  let rec run () =
    try
      let ch = input_char in_channel in ch :: (run ())
    with End_of_file ->
      ( close_in in_channel;
       [] )
  in list_to_string (run ());;
```

where `list_to_string` is:

```
let list_to_string s =
  let rec loop s n =
    match s with
    | [] -> String.make n '?'
    | car :: cdr ->
       let result = loop cdr (n + 1) in
       String.set result n car;
       result
  in
  loop s 0;;
```

funny thing is - I wrote `file_to_string` in tail recursion. This prevented the stack overflow, but for some reason went into an infinite loop. Oh, well...

Comment: "I wrote file_to_string in tail recursion". That is not tail recursive. You're leaking stack space. That's why you're getting stack overflows. Rewrite it as a tail recursive function and it will be more reliable and faster.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum string length is given by `Sys.max_string_length`. For a 32-bit system, it's quite short: 16777211. For a 64-bit system, it's 144115188075855863.

Unless you're using a 32-bit system, and your 4000-line file is over 16MB, I don't think you're hitting the string length limit.

A stack overflow is not what you'd expect to see when a string is too long.

It's more likely that you have infinite recursion, or possibly just a very deeply nested computation.